# XPath при выборке не находит все

Tags: html, html5, xpath

У меня задание:

> найди мне на любой странице все теги с атрибутом id, у которых предок div

Ищу таким способом:

```
/node()[descendant::div][@id]
```

или таким:

```
html/body/div/node()[@id]
```

но все равно не находит теги помещенные вот так:

```
<div>
    <p><button id='btn'></button></p>
</div>
```

Comment: html/body/div/node()[@id]

Comment: Ментор говорит что не правильно. Как исправить?

Comment: `html/body//div//node()[@id]`

Answer (score 0):

`//div//*[@id]` или так `//*[@id and ancestor::div]`